# Empty space appearing at the end of my carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, infinite-carousel

I have used [this script](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-infinite-carousel/) to create an infinite carousel on my website [here](http://cornertablehouston.com/). It's been customized with CSS so the first and last items are displayed half way.

If you keep clicking the right arrow, you will end up hitting an empty space at the end. So far I haven't been able to fix this. Can anybody offer any solutions?

Here is the relevant script:

```
/**
 * @author Stéphane Roucheray 
 * @extends jquery
 */
jQuery.fn.simplecarousel = function(previous, next, options){
    var sliderList = jQuery(this).children()[0];

    if (sliderList) {
        var increment = jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth(true),
        elmnts = jQuery(sliderList).children(),
        numElmts = elmnts.length,
        sizeFirstElmnt = increment,
        shownInViewport = Math.round(jQuery(this).width() / sizeFirstElmnt),
        firstElementOnViewPort = 1,
        isAnimating = false;

        for (i = 0; i < shownInViewport; i++) {
            jQuery(sliderList).css('width',(numElmts+shownInViewport)*increment + increment + "px");
            jQuery(sliderList).append(jQuery(elmnts[i]).clone());
        }

        jQuery(previous).click(function(event){
            if (!isAnimating) {
                if (firstElementOnViewPort == 1) {
                    jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "-" + numElmts * sizeFirstElmnt + "px");
                    firstElementOnViewPort = numElmts;
                }
                else {
                    firstElementOnViewPort--;
                }

                jQuery(sliderList).animate({
                    left: "+=" + increment,
                    y: 0,
                    queue: true
                }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
                isAnimating = true;
            }

        });

        jQuery(next).click(function(event){
            if (!isAnimating) {
                if (firstElementOnViewPort > numElmts) {
                    firstElementOnViewPort = 2;
                    jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "0px");
                }
                else {
                    firstElementOnViewPort++;
                }
                jQuery(sliderList).animate({
                    left: "-=" + increment,
                    y: 0,
                    queue: true
                }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
                isAnimating = true;
            }
        });
    }
};

#home-carousel-container {
    position: relative;
}
#home-carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#home-carousel ul {
    margin-left: -143px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#home-carousel li {
    float: left;
    height: 645px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 3px;
    width: 256px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what are the revelant adaptations (javascript/css) that you've added to the carousel?

Comment: try to include the code in your question.. to avoid link rot

Comment: Added the script I've used

Comment: The carousel should really show 4 full slides at once. The issue your facing is when you click left/right, it is removing that image to push it on the other end to create the continuous effect. It appears you've modified or incorrectly setup your carousel so that it hides half of the first/last visible slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment.

You have set a negative left-margin on your carousel causing it to hide half of an image. As a result when you click next/previous, it shows where an image is moved to create the continuous affect.

Witihin your css, I changed

```
#home-carousel ul{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: -143px;
}
```

to

```
#home-carousel ul{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

And had no problems what so ever.

[image: Screenshot of the page with the modification - In Chrome]

Comment: But if I remove that negative margin, I'd lose the effect that only half of my first and last images would appear instead of the whole image. :)

Comment: The carousel was not designed to do that. By using a negative margin, you are showing an area of the carousel that isn't intended to be shown and as a result, you're getting this effect. You may have to modify the logic used within the javascript that creates the carousel.